# Find column from row 1 header, and get column number (Excel.interop?

Tags: c#, excel

If I have an excelsheet like

Name, age, ID;

Peter, 35, 123456;

Is there a way for me to locate that age is column numner 2, by searching for age in row 1, or similar?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The fact that a column named "age" exists? Are you trying to extract all the data under the "age" column? Have you tried anything?

Comment: We use http://epplus.codeplex.com/ to manage our excel files, it allows you to query the excel doc using linq and easily determine things like the question your asking above

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is iterate through every column in the excel sheet and create a dictionary for every name/value pair. For example, 0 would map to Name, 1 would map to age and 2 would map to ID. From here, you may iterate through each row and for each column in that row look-up the name value pair (based on column ID). From there, you'll be able to determine the age.

Answer (score 0):

`Is there a way for me to locate that age is column numner 2, by searching for age in row 1, or similar?`

Yes. Assuming the rows are really kept in the format you specified, separated by a comma, you can easily use string's Split method, and Linq's Select method:

```
        string row = "Name, age, ID";
        int columnNum = Array.IndexOf(row.Split(',')
                                .Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray(), "age") + 1;
```

Explanation:

`row.Split(',')` - this method splits the string into an Array of strings: { "Name", "age", "ID" }

`.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray()` - this expression use LINQ to eliminate all the unnecessary spaces in the column Name (the method Trim() removes spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string).

`Array.IndexOf` - This method finds the index of the desired value ("age") within the array.

Indexes in C# begins at zero. namely, the index of "Name" is 0, and the index of "age" is actually 1 (and so on). To solve this I simply add 1 to the number returned by "IndexOf".

I'm warmly recommend to read any C# basic tutorial. it's all there :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the example of string search in Excel from MSDN: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a.aspx